# Can I use a pseudonym for my business if I already have an LLC set up?

Tags: business

I already have an LLC on which I plan to create a self-publishing company. The problem is I'd like to write for both children and adults, and thought having a pseudonym for the children's books would be best (two separate websites, of course). The name of my LLC is not my real name or the pseudonym.  If I have an LLC, do I need to also have a DBA for my pseudonym if I receive payments under that name, or is there a way I can just use the LLC for payments made to either my real name or the pen name?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: When you say you want to "use" a pseudonym, do you mean putting it on the cover of a book, or putting it on some piece of paperwork which you file with the government? Because, frankly, the only such piece of government paperwork which I could imagine specifically needing the *author's* name (as opposed to the LLC owner's name) would be the author's personal tax return (for which it is fairly obvious that you can't use a pseudonym). The publisher is of course under no obligation to tell the general public that its owner and the author of the book are the same person.

Comment: USA (specifically, my business is out of NJ)

Comment: I guess the pen name would be used in place of my real legal name on the actual book, website. I am not sure about how it works for legal documents, which is what I am asking. Despite having an LLC with one brand name and using a pen name on the product, do I still file a DBA or can I get paid using the brand name of the business? I don't think people can pay me under the pen name because it is not my real name but I don't know how it works.